# Get total of items inside a metafield in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to show the total number of items inside a multiple field metafield in Shopify.

I am first assigning the metafield value in Liquid:

```
{% assign gallery = article.metafields.custom.gallery.value %}
```

To later ask for the total number of elements:

```
{{ gallery.size }}
```

Does someone know why this shows a blank result?
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What's the metafield type and what do you get when you simply display value?

Comment: Your best bet is to first off ensure that value has a value. Just print it out in your template source code. Once you do that, you can then examine it. The biggest problem with your question is that it is not clear what you are expecting here by asking for a size? A size is usually associated with the number of elements in an array, but Metafields do not naturally contain any arrays. Obviously, a JSON string could, but you fail to mention anything other than multiple field, something that does not exist. Once you frame your question better, perhaps someone can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I think `{{ gallery.count }}` will solve this issue.

There's a little bit of info here:
https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#product_list

I think it's annoying that `.size` returns nothing.